# Spring Boot Application intermittently returns HTTP 404 when deployed to a Tomcat Server using Parallel Deployment

Tags: deployment, spring-boot, tomcat8

We are developing an application using `Spring Boot` plus `Spring web starter`. We use `Go Pipeline` and `Parallel Deployment` feature of `Apache Tomcat 7` to deploy war file to a standalone Tomcat Server. [ref](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

When running the application we can see the logs loading controllers, services and requests, etc.

Once the container is up, the initial requests occasionally lead to an ugly 404.

However, this is an intermittent behavior. Once you refresh browser, subsequent request works.

We wonder what could be the root cause of the intermittent 404 response.